# Здравствуйте, пишу php код для удаления из кода страницы ошибки, не работает одна из строк. Это нужно для validator.w3.org

Tags: php, css, str-replace, worpdress

В стиле wordpress, подключаемом темой astra допущена ошибка в css
[image: кусок подключаемого на странице кода]

В этой длинной строке есть вот такое чудо:

```
.menu-link,{height:100%;-webkit-box-align:center;-webkit-align-items:center;-moz-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;-js-display:flex;display:flex;}
```

Соответственно мне нужно

```
.menu-link,{
```

Заменить на

```
.menu-link{
```

Добавила на сайт php код:

```
function callback($buffer) {
    $buffer= str_replace('type="text/javascript"', '', $buffer);
    $buffer= str_replace("type='text/javascript'", '', $buffer);

    $buffer= str_replace('type="text/css"', '', $buffer);
    $buffer= str_replace("type='text/css'", '', $buffer);

    $buffer= str_replace('menu-link,{', 'menu-link{', $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

function buffer_start() {
    ob_start("callback");
}

function buffer_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
}

add_action('wp_head', 'buffer_start', 99);
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end', 99);
```

Тут еще много строк для замены разных ошибок, все они работают, кроме вышеупомянутого .menu-link,{
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте вывести `$buffer` перед `$buffer= str_replace('menu-link,{', 'menu-link{', $buffer);`, возможно, строка отличается.

Comment: т.е. просто написать
echo $buffer
до начала замены?
Если так, то вообще ничего не выводится